# Phalcon getJsonRawBody not working with GET request

Tags: jquery, ajax, phalcon

I am working on an API using Phalcon.  I am in the trial/error phase learning both Phalcon and the proper way to build a REST API using this framework.

My issue is that when making an ajax call via jQuery to my API with type: "GET" Phalcon is not able to parse the request using getJsonRawBody.  When I run the same ajax call via jQuery with type: "POST" it works.

---

Here is my ajax request.

```
$('.start').click(function() {
    var arr = {timestamp:'<?=time();?>'};
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Api-Key", "<?=$api_key;?>");
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Hash", "<?=$hash;?>");
        },
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: "http://api-dev.fancompetition.com/my-rest-api/api/robots/",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#data').html(data);
    });
});
```

On the server side I have:

$vars = $app->request->getJsonRawBody();

So now if you change type to POST I am able to get the contents.  When type is GET than my variable vars is blank.  Any idea as to why?

Comment: Got the answer.

Basically GET request typically does not have a message body. Pass as a parameter in the url and capture it properly on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

GET request doesn't have a body. If you need to pass your data, you can add it query string. For example:

```
http://api-dev.fancompetition.com/my-rest-api/api/robots/?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

You can retrieve via `$app->request->get()` and then decode json manually using `json_decode`